# Transform rows and column and create a similarity dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I already have a normalized dataset:

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame([('red apple', 'ripe banana', 0.3),
            ('red apple', 'hot pepper', 0.4),
            ('red apple','sweet kiwi', 0.5),
            ('ripe banana','hot pepper', 0.6),
            ('ripe banana','sweet kiwi', 0.7),
            ('hot pepper','sweet kiwi', 0.8)], ["phrase1", "phrase2", 'common_persent'])
df.show()

+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|    phrase1|    phrase2|common_persent|
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|  red apple|ripe banana|           0.3|
|  red apple| hot pepper|           0.4|
|  red apple| sweet kiwi|           0.5|
|ripe banana| hot pepper|           0.6|
|ripe banana| sweet kiwi|           0.7|
| hot pepper| sweet kiwi|           0.8|
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

I want to create a matrix of similarity using pyspark. The result should look like this:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|    phrases|red apple|ripe banana|hot pepper|sweet kiwi|
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
|  red apple|      1.0|        0.3|       0.4|       0.5|
|ripe banana|      0.3|        1.0|       0.6|       0.7|
| hot pepper|      0.4|        0.6|       1.0|       0.8|
| sweet kiwi|      0.5|        0.7|       0.8|       1.0|
+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Thus, there are units on the diagonal, and above / below the values from the columns `average`. My problem is that, I don't quite understand how to make the units on the diagonal.

Comment: What're the values in the symmetric matrix supposed to mean ? If your tuples aren't unique what aggregation are you using ?

Comment: This is the percentage of phrases prevalence, i.e. average. I did not use the aggregation functions, but I counted myself. First there was one column where all the phrases were. All phrases were counted using count and divided by the mean, thus the percentage was obtained. These values are in the common_persent column. The problem is, when changing the positions of rows with columns, I need to add a diagonal with ones if the phrases match, so the percentage is 1.0

Comment: If you know how to fill values off the diagonal, fill them first, and then use fillna(1) to fill in the diagonal values.

Comment: The problem is that I do not understand how I can transpose my dataframe into a similarity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform your dataframe into a similarity matrix, you have to follow several steps:

- first, create the list of permutations of phrase1/phrase2 by creating an array and then using `explode` on this array
- then, pivot your dataframe as explained in [Lamanus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043434/6807769)
- finally, fill `null` values with `1.0` using `fillna`
- optionally, reorder your `phrases` column

The complete code is as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
  'permutations',
  F.array(
    F.struct(F.col('phrase1').alias('first'), F.col('phrase2').alias('second')),
    F.struct(F.col('phrase2').alias('first'), F.col('phrase1').alias('second'))
  )
) \
  .drop('phrase1', 'phrase2') \
  .select(F.explode('permutations'), F.col('common_persent')) \
  .select("col.*", "common_persent") \
  .groupBy(F.col('first').alias('phrases')) \
  .pivot('second') \
  .agg(F.first('common_persent')) \
  .fillna(1.0) \
  .orderBy('phrases')
```

With your `df` dataframe, it gives you the following `result` dataframe:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
|phrases    |hot pepper|red apple|ripe banana|sweet kiwi|
+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
|hot pepper |1.0       |0.4      |0.6        |0.8       |
|red apple  |0.4       |1.0      |0.3        |0.5       |
|ripe banana|0.6       |0.3      |1.0        |0.7       |
|sweet kiwi |0.8       |0.5      |0.7        |1.0       |
+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pivot your dataframe.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.groupBy('phrase1').pivot('phrase2').agg(f.first('common_persent')).show()

+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|    phrase1|hot pepper|ripe banana|sweet kiwi|
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  red apple|       0.4|        0.3|       0.5|
|ripe banana|       0.6|       null|       0.7|
| hot pepper|      null|       null|       0.8|
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```